# File not being unregistered by Inno Setup during uninstall when it is also matched by a wildcard Files section entry

Tags: inno-setup

I currently use the following code to install and register a DLL.

```
[Files]
Source: "Keys\Sentinel\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: recursesubdirs 32bit 
Source: "Keys\Sentinel\hasp_com_windows.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: regserver 32bit noregerror;
```

This works great during an install operation, and the logfile shows that the file has been successfully registered.  My problem is that during an uninstall the file is not being unregistered, and the uninstall logfile contains nothing about the file other than that it has been deleted, which it has.  What could cause the file to not be unregistered?  The help file says it should be.

Comment: If you need the entire files I will zip them and upload them somewhere.  Otherwise, here are the relevant lines.  Nope.  I had trouble pasting them into this reply. The files are here [link](https://www.xlrotor.com/temp/INNO-logs.zip)   The INNO script is there, too.

Comment: The DLL is in a folder with other files that don't need to be registered.  So in the [Files] section there is an item to install all files in that folder, but without a regserver flag.  Then after that there is another line for just the DLL with a regserver flag.  The install log shows these two attempts to install the file, the first succeeds.  The second attempt says it will skip the file, but register it later.  The log file near the end shows it was registered. Could the skipping part cause the uninstaller to skip unregistering the file?

Comment: I created a minimal example to reproduce the problem, and along the way I found a solution.  Putting the [Files] Source: line with the regserver flag before the line without this flag results in the DLL being unregistered when uninstalling.  So it looks like the skipping business does not prevent registration, but does prevent unregistration.  Is that by design?  When the application folder contains lots of files, and just a few need to be registered, what is the recommended way to do this? Is it to install the few files first with regserver, followed by a * line without this flag?

Comment: [Files]  
Source: "Keys\Sentinel\\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: recursesubdirs 32bit noregerror;  
Source: "Keys\Sentinel\hasp_com_windows.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: regserver 32bit noregerror;  
  
  
The lines above did not unregister the file during uninstall, but if the * line is put last, then it was unregistered.  Sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the behavior you are seeing.

In general you should never install the same file to the same destination using two distinct entries in the `[Files]` section. That always leads to an unexpected behaviour. Like in this case.

The right solution is to exclude the DLL from the wildcard entry:

```
[Files]
Source: "Keys\Sentinel*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Excludes: "hasp_com_windows.dll";  \
    Flags: recursesubdirs 32bit
Source: "Keys\Sentinel\hasp_com_windows.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: regserver 32bit noregerror
```